# LookupEidt in Dxgrid giving error 'object must implement Iconvertible'

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, devexpress

I am using DevExpress v2010 vol2 for WPF.

I have to use lookupedit in  dxgrid when adding/editing iformation in a column of grid.

I dont know why it is giving 'object must implement Iconvertible' when i am selecting  value from LookupEdit.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are having the same problem as the problem posted [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B182475.aspx) at the DevExpress Support Center? If so, it seems that there is a bug in v2010 vol 2.4 which is fixed in v2010 vol 2.5

Comment: i am using WPF. the link you specified is for .Net (SilverLight)

Answer (score 0):

Set the ValueMember / Displaymember Propertys.